# Action Script 3 move objects by x,y

Tags: actionscript-3

I have homework for my programming lessons. My task is to create balloon shooter game. I done everything in my way, balloons are spawning, counter works. But i cant make them move upwards, i know how to move = y++. That is my problem, i cant figure out where and how. Code below:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
var c = 0;
circle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, handlerMouseDown);
circle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, handlerMouseUp);
function handlerMouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void{
    circle.startDrag();
}

function handlerMouseUp(event:MouseEvent):void{
    circle.stopDrag();
    var i:int;
    for (i=numChildren-1;i>=0;i--)
        if (getChildAt(i) is MyRectangle){
            if (circle.hitTestObject(getChildAt(i))){
                removeChildAt(i);
                c++;
                score.text =c;
            }
        }
}

var moveUp:Boolean = true;
var b:Boolean = false;
var t1 = 1000;
var t2 = 1002;
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(t1); 
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, runMany);
myTimer.start();

function runMany(event:TimerEvent):void {
    b = true;
    t1+=50;
}

var myTimer2:Timer = new Timer(t2); 
myTimer2.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, runMany2);
myTimer2.start();

function runMany2(event:TimerEvent):void {
    b = false;
    t2 -=50;
}

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handlerEnterFrame);
function handlerEnterFrame(event:Event):void{
var rect:MyRectangle = new MyRectangle();

addChildAt(rect,0);
if(b){
    rect.x = int(Math.random()*width);
    rect.y = int(Math.random()*height)
    }
}

circle.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handlerEnterFrame2);
function handlerEnterFrame2(event:Event):void{
    Mouse.hide();
    circle.startDrag(true);
}
```

Comment: You need an Array with all your balloons in it, so you can apply changes in each of their `y` properties, so they appear to float upwards. You need an array so that all the balloons can float upwards at the same time.

Comment: Your ENTER_FRAME handlers are out of place. First one spawns MyRectangle on screen. Second starts dragging. This isn't normally done every frame. Spawn object based on some condition (e.g. last balloon popped) and drag when left mouse button is down. EnterFrame handler is for updating coordinates.

Comment: Yeah i found it too, fixed. ok i did it, just like AlexW said - i put them i array and then foreach move. Thx

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see from your description is that you have your coordinates wrong somewhat. The top-left of the screen is (0,0), and if you use `y++`, the object will move downwards, rather than up. `y--` will move it up...albeit slowly.

Second thing is, you need to make some sort of update cycle. Your `Balloon` class should have an `update()` function, which is called every frame for each balloon. In the balloons' update function is where you would want to put `y--` (or something else to alter its position). You might want to also do collision detection there as well, once you get to that. You'll want to put all the balloons (and everything else that changes over time) in an array, and each frame call `update()` on each item in the array with a `for` loop. Whenever you add something to the stage, it should also be added to the array of objects updated every frame.

Comment: What happened to having a balloon class with event listeners and methods inside the balloon class? AS3 is a OOP language, don't encourage habits like putting everything in a single class.